# How to set multiple parent at the same time

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a store manager. My store can hold multiple categories. A product could belong to multiple categories. For example, if you would sell computer online, you would have  two categories.

> Motherboard
>
> Dell

And my product

> Intel Core i5-4670K

Would belong to both categories. My problem is that the current template I'm in would need 2 Controllers : My ArrayController that holds multiple ObjectControler of my Categories and the one that holds the selected current product. Since a picture is worth a thousand words here's what I'm trying to accomplish :

[image]

When the user click on the small arrow, it would add/remove the relation between my product and the selected category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need multiple controllers, you can add a "needs" property to your main controller.

```
App.ListController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: [ 'otherController' ]
});
```

Then, in your template, you can use:

```
{{controller.otherController.foo}}
```

Comment: Woah, I'm trying to soak up all this information. Makes only 5 weeks that I started learning Ember and I totally forgot about that. I'll work on it and get back to you with result, but I think it should work.